# How to store image using Downloader Manager downloaded image name in external storage in android

Tags: android, local-storage, android-download-manager

Hello I am downloading image from Url using Downloadmanager. and i perfectly manage to download that image.but i dont know where it store the image for future reference.

I want to store it in download folder.how to do that to store in download folder.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button downld;
private DownloadManager dm;
private long enqueue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    downld=(Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {
                        String uriString = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                       File ifdir1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "EPP");
                        if (!ifdir1.exists())
                            ifdir1.mkdirs();
                       File imagefile1 = new File(ifdir1.getPath() + File.separator +c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));

                      Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(imagefile1);
                        Log.v("Abhi", "" +  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE)));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    downld.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse("https://www.eprintpost.com/images/homepage/slider0.gif"));
            enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

        }
    });
}
}
```

How to download image in download folder with image name.

Thansk in advance

Comment: Hey! I have did the same using AsyncTask. If you want to use the same then I will provide you the same.

Comment: Is there any different way except AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

for saving downloaded images in downloads folder you need to write following code `DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);`

**For more refer following code**

```
    public static void downloadThroughManager(String imageUrl, Context context) {


                    File path = new File(imageUrl);
                    String fileName = path.getName();
                    final DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setTitle(fileName);
                    request.setDescription(fileName);
                    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                    long ref = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);




        final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                long downloadReference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                Log.i("GenerateTurePDfAsync", "Download completed");


                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(downloadReference);

                Cursor cur = downloadManager.query(query);

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);



                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                        String uriString = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                        Toast.makeText(context, "File has been downloaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                        int columnReason = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                        int reason = cur.getInt(columnReason);
                        switch(reason){

                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed.File is corrupt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed.Http Error Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed due to insufficient space in internal storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;

                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed. Http Code Error Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
                                Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };


        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
```